# Python - дозапись списков в json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Mне надо записать получаемые списки в json. Списки записываются, когда они получаются:

```
try:
with codecs.open(FILENAME1, "a", "utf_8_sig") as file:
    json.dump(label,file)
except:
    with codecs.open(FILENAME1, "w", "utf_8_sig") as file:
        json.dump(label,file)
```

Так как функция дозаписи вызывается не один раз, то на выходе выходит не валидный *json* файл. `label` - это список списков, *json*  файл должен быть списком списков.

Есть идеи как сделать верную дозапись?

Comment: 1 Считать весь json в память / 2 Изменить нужные данные / 3 Переписать файл с json новыми данными

Comment: @gil9red понял, спасибо, если выложите как ответ, приму его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если объект `json` помещается в память, можно в нее считать, поменять `json` и после сохранить:

Есть файл `counter.json` с содержимым: `{"counter": 0}`.

Скрипт при каждом вызове увеличит `counter` на единицу, а после сохранит `json`:

```
import json

file_name = 'counter.json'
json_data = json.load(open(file_name, encoding='utf-8'))

# Изменение объекта
json_data['counter'] += 1

# Сохранение
json.dump(json_data, open(file_name, mode='w', encoding='utf-8'))
```